run a large language model (LLM) as a .so shared library on Android for Unity3D integration
I'm developing a Unity3D application for Android, and I need to integrate a large language model (LLM). From what I understand, I would need to compile the LLM as a .so shared library to use it on Android.
Has anyone done this before or know of any LLMs that are already available in this format? Any advice on how to approach this or resources that might help would be appreciated.

LLMs are probably not something you want to run locally, as they tend to be gigabytes in size and require specialized hardware to run efficiently. Better to use an LLM API like Gemini over the intertubes.  I'm not a Unity expert, but my experience with Unity apps is they tend to require internet access, so I assume there must be a way to call APIs.

On mobile Android has Tensorflow Lite, Google's MLKit and I am aware of ONNX Runtime for Android Any solution will be more restrictive than the full size models used in the cloud or on PC desktops, but will depend on your use case.
